# jenkins role based plugin issue with okta

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, okta

I integrated my jenkins app with OKTA(SSO). connection between okta and jenkins works good.

Issue: i am trying to map OKTA user groups to jenkins via role based plugin(in jenkins). By default role based plugin gives anonymous admin permissions on jenkins, once i remove anonymous access, OKTA groups losing access to jenkins. I am no sure why this is happening please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Provide read açcess of jobs to okta user and you can assign other access level  also e.g start build etc . 
You need read access to see Jobs as okta users will be considered in authorised user. after that user which are not registered with jenkins (anonymous ) will not able to access as you will remove anonymous user access